# Get list of maven dependencies of org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to get a list of dependencies of some maven artifacts using `org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject`.

My code is like this.

```java
public List<Dependencies> loadProject() {
    Model mavenModel = new Model();
    mavenModel.setModelVersion("4.0.0");
    mavenModel.setGroupId("org");
    mavenModel.setArtifactId("wso2");
    mavenModel.setVersion("1.0.0");

    addDependency(mavenModel, "com.google.inject", "guice", "4.2.2");
    addDependency(mavenModel, "ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic", "1.2.3");

    MavenProject mavenProject = new MavenProject(mavenModel);

    //******* Need to resolve dependencies of `mavenProject` and *******
    //******* get the list of dependencies of this project.    *******

    return dependencies;
}

private static void addDependency(Model mavenModel, String groupId, String artifactId, String version) {


Dependency dependency = new Dependency();
    dependency.setGroupId(groupId);
    dependency.setArtifactId(artifactId);
    dependency.setVersion(version);
    mavenModel.addDependency(dependency);
}
```

Basically I'm trying to get the dependency tree results which returns by `mvn dependency:tree` command as a list by programmatically.

**Example**
For the artifacts:

- `com.google.inject:guide:4.2.2`
- `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3`

Dependency list:

```
List = [
com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.2.2:compile,
javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile,
aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile,
com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.1-android:compile,
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile,
org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile,
com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile,
com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile,
org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile,
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile,
ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile,
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
]
```

Comment: The similar question is answered by Tunaki at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638138/find-all-direct-dependencies-of-an-artifact-on-maven-central

Comment: @NikhilZurunge But here I do not want to create a maven project by creating a pom file. I want to use `org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject`

Comment: The information are only available during a maven build which means in the context of a maven plugin. If you simply read the pom file you don't have those informations....There is no resolution of dependencyManagement (if you use it) etc.

Comment: I want to know is there any java method or class to resolve dependencies from `MavenProject` object

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `public Set<Artifact> getArtifacts()` of your `MavenProject` class which returns a set of artifacts representing all dependencies that the project has, including transitive ones.

NB: Contents are lazily populated, so depending on what phases have run dependencies in some scopes won't be included. eg. if only compile phase has run, dependencies with scope test won't be included.

All the information are coming from the documentation that you can find [here](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getArtifacts()).

Comment: I guess you assume that the code should run during a Maven build (as a Maven plugin), but the OP wants to run it outside of a Maven run.

Comment: @JFMeier yes, you are right. Seems I don't have a solution for this use case :/